# Variable is declared but error messages says not

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the stored procedure shown below, I get this error, but I am declaring the `@Remarks`, so I cannot see what is the issue:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure sp_Insert_EMR_PATIENT_CHECK_TRACKING, Line 53
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@REMARKS".

Code:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_EMR_PATIENT_CHECK_TRACKING] 
     @HOUR int,
     @TIME int,
     @MRN nchar(10),
     @NURSING_UNIT varchar(12),
     @CHECK_DATE datetime,
     @MONITOR_CODE nchar(10),
     @Remarks nvarchar(500),
     @Pain_Level int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    If @Remarks = 'undefined'
    BEGIN
        SET @Remarks = null
    END

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM [OGEN].[EMR_PATIENT_CHECK_TRACKING]
                   WHERE CHECK_DATE = @CHECK_DATE
                     AND MRN = @MRN
                     AND NURSING_UNIT = @NURSING_UNIT
                     AND HOUR = @HOUR
                     AND TIME = @TIME
                     AND MONITOR_CODE = @MONITOR_CODE)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [OGEN].[EMR_PATIENT_CHECK_TRACKING] ([CHECK_DATE], [MRN], [NURSING_UNIT], [HOUR], [TIME], [MONITOR_CODE], [Pain_Level])
        VALUES (@CHECK_DATE, @MRN, @NURSING_UNIT, @HOUR, @TIME, @MONITOR_CODE, @Pain_Level)

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM [OGEN].[EMR_PATIENT_CHECK_TRACKING_REMARK]
                       WHERE CHECK_DATE = @CHECK_DATE
                         AND MRN = @MRN
                         AND NURSING_UNIT = @NURSING_UNIT
                         AND HOUR = @HOUR
                         AND MONITOR_CODE = @MONITOR_CODE)
        BEGIN
           INSERT INTO [OGEN].[EMR_PATIENT_CHECK_TRACKING_REMARK] ([CHECK_DATE], [MRN], [NURSING_UNIT], [HOUR], [MONITOR_CODE], [REMARKS])
           VALUES (@CHECK_DATE, @MRN, @NURSING_UNIT, @HOUR, @MONITOR_CODE, ISNULL(@REMARKS,''))
        END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [OGEN].[EMR_PATIENT_CHECK_TRACKING_REMARK]
        SET REMARKS = ISNULL(@Remarks,REMARKS)
        WHERE CHECK_DATE = @CHECK_DATE
          AND [MRN] = @MRN
          AND [NURSING_UNIT] = @NURSING_UNIT
          AND [HOUR] = @HOUR     
          AND [MONITOR_CODE] = @MONITOR_CODE
    END
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
      UPDATE [OGEN].[EMR_PATIENT_CHECK_TRACKING] 
      SET [Pain_Level]=@Pain_Level
      WHERE CHECK_DATE = @CHECK_DATE
        AND MRN = @MRN
        AND NURSING_UNIT = @NURSING_UNIT
        AND HOUR = @HOUR
        AND TIME = @TIME
        AND MONITOR_CODE = @MONITOR_CODE

      UPDATE [OGEN].[EMR_PATIENT_CHECK_TRACKING_REMARK]
      SET REMARKS = Isnull(@Remarks,REMARKS)
      WHERE CHECK_DATE = @CHECK_DATE
        AND [MRN] = @MRN
        AND [NURSING_UNIT] = @NURSING_UNIT
        AND [HOUR] = @HOUR 
        AND [MONITOR_CODE] = @MONITOR_CODE
   END
END
```

Comment: It seems that your server is set to be case-sensitivity so `@REMARKS` is a different variable than your `@Remarks`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter @Remarks is declared using camel case and later in your stored procedure you reference it as @REMARKS - it could be that you are using a case-sensitive collation and this will result in the error you are seeing.

If your database collation contains "_CI" (e.g. Latin1_General_CI_AS) then it is case-insensitive, if it contains "_CS" it is a case-sensitive collation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error information, your server is set to be case-sensitive. This can be confirmed via,

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));
```

Running the above statement on my case-sensitive server returns, `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`.

To bypass that error, you must rename `@REMARKS` to `@Remarks` which you had defined or append a `COLLATE` statement to change the sensitivity to be case-insensitive. On my server, this would be `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

The better choice would be to remain consistent with your variable naming convention.

On the same case-sensitive server,

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(10) = 'hello'
SELECT @VALUE                                        <<< ERROR.


SELECT @value COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   <<< returns, 'hello'
```